# Show that if $||g||_2 = 1$, $\int_\mathbb{R} x^2 g^2(x) dx \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} \xi^2 |\mathcal{F}g|^2(\xi) dx \geq \pi / 2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-transform

I want to show that, given $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $g, xg, g' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} g^2 d\lambda = 1$, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2 g^2(x) dx \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} \xi^2 |\mathcal{F}g|^2(\xi) dx \geq \pi / 2
\end{equation}
First, I thought that it looked a little bit like the Hölder inequality, with:
\begin{equation}
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2 g^2(x) dx \cdot \int_\mathbb{R} \xi^2 |\mathcal{F}g|^2(\xi) dx \geq (\int_\mathbb{R} |x g(x) \cdot x (\mathcal{F}g)(x)| dx)^2)
\end{equation}
However, I have no idea how I could bound the second part. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Knowing a bit of quantum physics is actually quite useful here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle (see *"Proof of the Kennard inequality using wave mechanics"* and try to adapt the proof). Alternatively, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253844 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471066 for some more mathematical approaches.